# Spring MQTT subscriber configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to read subscribed topic messages through Spring MQTT client.

```
<mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter id="mqttInbound"
    client-id="mySpringServer"
    url="tcp://localhost:1883"
    topics="foo2015"
    auto-startup="true"
    client-factory="clientFactory"
    channel="fileChannel"/>
```

<del>Rather than having a "`fileChannel`" channel, I like to handle them via Spring MQTT client.
Ex: `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`</del>

<del>Can I use `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` as a bean and refer the "`mqttInbound`"?</del>

<del>All incoming messages to the "`mqttInbound`" redirect to `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. Can I do this?</del>

**Update:** 
Can I redirect incoming messages to a bean? Is there any interface that I can use?

For example:

```
<mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter ... channel="msgChannel" />
<bean id="msgChannel" class="org.channel.AnyMessageReader"/>
```

I have seen the below example, but I'm not sure exactly that is what I'm looking for.

```
<int:channel id="channel_01" />
<int:service-activator id="serviceActivator" input-channel="channel_01" ref="msgService" method="setMessage" />
<bean id="msgService" class="org.channel.AnyMessageService"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, or you misunderstood Spring Integration a bit, or I have missed anything from your question.

The `<mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter>` is a high-level component for the `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`:

1. `MqttNamespaceHandler`

   ```
   this.registerBeanDefinitionParser("message-driven-channel-adapter",  new MqttMessageDrivenChannelAdapterParser());
   ```
2. `MqttMessageDrivenChannelAdapterParser`

   ```
           BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                   .genericBeanDefinition(MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.class);
   ```

So, what is the point to wrap `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` to the `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` ?

Do you have some extension for that? So, you must declare the regular `<bean>` for your customization, but `outputChannel` of the `MessageProducer` is required anyway.

Comment: I just updated the question. I think I have no idea here. I checked on spring docs, but no result. I think I should definitely need some background knowledge about Spring-JMS first to understand this.